# how can i see if an open filehandle is writeable or not on a linux system?

Tags: linux, lsof

I can see with lsof that a process has an open filehandle for a particular file, but is there a way that I can see what kind of filehandle (ex: r, rw) it is?

Answer (score 5):

From the [lsof manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof)

```
  FD is followed by one of these characters, describing the mode 
  under which the file is open:

       r for read access;
       w for write access;
       u for read and write access;
       space if mode unknown and no lock
            character follows;
       `-' if mode unknown and lock
            character follows.
```

So in the line

```
liferea    3264    dennis    0r   CHR    1,3    0t0     1049 /dev/null
```

You can see that stdin is open in read only mode

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, I see this is part of the normal output of lsof:

FD  is  followed by one of these characters, describing the mode under which the file is open:

r for read access;
 w for write access;
 u for read and write access;